# Make a transparent canvas not transparent (trying to override the default DragShadow look with drag and drop in Android)

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

The default look and position for a drag shadow is the view past in made transparent and centered on your touch.  I want it to look solid and the view to begin at your touch.

I have descended the DragShadowBuilder and overrode "onProvideShadowMetrics" and "onDrawShadow".  I have got the positioning how I want but I don't know how to turn off the transparent.

Here is touch listener with the call creating my dragShadowBuilder and the dragShadowBuilder class:

```
private OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Item current = (Item) ((View) v.getTag()).getTag();
            //ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("test", "testText");
            View dragView = (View) v.getTag();//the on touch view is just the "grid" image.  It holds the whole view in it's tag
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new ItemDragShadowBuilder(dragView, 
                                new Point(v.getWidth()/2, v.getHeight()/2));
            v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, current, 0);
            dragView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }       
    }

};

private static class ItemDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

    private Point touchPoint = null;
    private Point sizePoint = null;
    private View dragView = null;

    public ItemDragShadowBuilder(View dragView, Point touchPoint) {
        super();
        sizePoint = new Point(dragView.getWidth(), dragView.getHeight());
        this.touchPoint = touchPoint;
        this.dragView = dragView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics (Point size, Point touch) {
        size.set(sizePoint.x, sizePoint.y);
        touch.set(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        dragView.draw(canvas);
        //How do I change the transparency?
        //super.onDrawShadow(canvas);
    }



}
```

Here is my current screen with an item being dragged:

[image: My current screen]

Note the transparent look.  What I want it to look like is similar to the Google Current app below when you long click on your subscriptions and select "re-order".  You'll notice the view looks solid.

[image: Google Currents]

How can I make my drag shadow solid?

Comment: I am in desperate need for a solution to this...

Comment: I, too, am looking for a solutions. would be mega-grateful for a hint

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Its been 3 years!